# cannot find one or more components. please reinstall application error while installing python tools

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, msdn

Please help.I cant install python tools on visual studio 2013. The installer works fine but towards end of installation it says "cannot find  one or more components please reinstall the application.And the installer closes with an error message "installation stopped prematurely".
Ive already tired devnav/resetuserdata.

Answer (score 1):

To clean up the installation, you can just delete its installation folder and restart VS.

In case you would like to be extra careful, you can run devenv.exe /setup from a VS command prompt before restarting

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, tried almost all the tricks but none worked out. In the end I re-installed the latest version of VS, repaired the old version and the issue was resolved.